# Why join query give different result than subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery, northwind

I am learning PostgreSQL and working with [Nortwind database](https://github.com/pthom/northwind_psql)

Now I am testing `JOIN` and subquery with `ANY`
I want select all `product_name` of which exactly 10 were ordered (column `quantity` from `order_details`)
So I have 2 different queries:

```
SELECT product_name FROM products
WHERE product_id = ANY(
    SELECT product_id FROM order_details
    WHERE quantity = 10
)
```

and

```
SELECT products.product_name FROM products
JOIN order_details ON order_details.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE order_details.quantity = 10
```

But they are giving different results!
Firts one gives:
[Only 60 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvebd.png)
And the second one gives: [181 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68YLY.png)

Why is that and which result is right?

Comment: They return a different number of rows between they are completely different queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query will output each `products` row at most once.

The second query can have several result rows for a single `products` row: one for each matching `order_details` row.

Which of the queries is better depends on your requirements.